# How do I keep track of the original codebase in a forked project?

Tags: git, repository

I have a bit of a complicated situation with a project that I am managing with git (on github, if relevant).

For most projects, my git workflow (1) looks like this:

```
main repo (upstream)
|
|_repo A (origin)
```

I modify the code in a branch of my own repo (`repo A`), then push to `repo`. After the PR is merged, I sync `repo A` using the commands:

```
pull upstream master
push origin master
```

Nothing special here, it is a basic git workflow, and other people can easily collaborate to the project.

I am now working on another project with a more complicated workflow, which looks like this:

```
original repo
|
|_main repo (upstream)
  |
  |_repo A (origin)
```

Basically, the `main repo` is a fork of the `original repo` which is not actively developed anymore. The `main` fork is now the *official version* of the codebase and the users pull/push their changes to/from the `main repo` (as above).
However, the `original repo` has some occasional updates that may need incorporating in the `main repo`. Obviously `main` will contain changes that `original` does not, so the simple workflow (1) is not good anymore.

To keep the official version in sync, I download the latest version of `original`, diff it against an offline copy of `main` made at the time of forking, and manually add the changes to (for example) `repo A`. Usually, it's not a lot of files or of changes, so it's doable, but it's far from an ideal solution.  I am not a big expert on git, beyond the basic stuff, and my question is if there is a better way to organize the workflow. Or maybe there is some clever "git-fu" technique?

Pushing from `main` to `original` (i.e. making it the upstream) or taking ownership of `original` are not options, for a number of reasons.

Comment: Does the main repo get updated on original repo? If so -> rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add configure multiple remotes using `git remote` command. So in your case you can configure a remote for original repo and get updates from it using `git pull remote-name branch --rebase`. Based on what's been in main and original you may get merge conflicts which you may have to fix manually.

Comment: I am wondering if it is better to keep a branch of `repo A` for the purpose of tracking `original repo` and do `git pull remote-name branch`from this dedicated branch. Or is it just going to make things more complicated?

Comment: Depends on what changes you need from upstream. May be you can keep a separate branch and then do cherry picking the commits you need to your main branch without breaking any changes